Is Hartshorne's exercise II.6.10 (c) missing some hints?
The setting is the following: let $X$ be a noetherian scheme, define $K(X)$ the Grothendieck group obtained from coherent sheaves on $X$ (free abelian group modulo relations from short exact sequences). If $Y$ is a closed subscheme of $X$, the question asserts that the following is an exact sequence
$$K(Y) \rightarrow K(X) \rightarrow K(X \setminus Y)\rightarrow 0$$
where the maps are induced from the pushforward and restriction of sheaves. I am interested in showing exactness in the middle.
The hint provided in Hartshorne reads:

For exactness in the middle, show that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$, whose support is contained in $Y$, then there is a filtration $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}_0 \subseteq \mathcal{F}_1 \subseteq ... \subseteq \mathcal{F}_n = 0$ such that each $\mathcal{F}_i / \mathcal{F}_{i+1}$ is the pushforward of a coherent sheaf on $Y$.

I understand the proof of the hint, my issue is that this hint seems insufficient to conclude. If I understand correctly, the way this hint is supposed to work, is that given a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathcal{F}_{|X \setminus Y}$ vanishes in $K(X \setminus Y)$, we then argue that $\mathcal{F}_{|X \setminus Y}$ itself is zero, so $\mathcal{F}$ has support in $Y$, and the hint expresses $[\mathcal{F}]_X$ (the class of $\mathcal{F}$ in $K(X)$) as a sum of elements of $K(Y)$. I am not quite satisfied with this argument, for two reasons:

the fact that $[\mathcal{F}_{|X \setminus Y}]_{X \setminus Y}$ is zero does not a priori imply that $\mathcal{F}_{|X \setminus Y}$ itself is zero. Question (a) essentially shows that if $A$ is a PID, any coherent sheaf over $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ given by a torsion module is zero in the Grothendieck group. So I suppose the right statement should be: if $[\mathcal{F}_{|X \setminus Y}]_{X \setminus Y}=0$, then either $\mathcal{F}_{|X \setminus Y}=0$, or $[\mathcal{F}]_X=0$. Again, this does not seem obvious to me (we could have a short exact sequence over $X \setminus Y$ that lifts to sheaves over $X$ which no longer fit into an exact sequence).
more generally, an element of $\operatorname{ker}(K(X) \rightarrow K(X \setminus Y))$ need not be of the form $[\mathcal{F}]$ for a single sheaf. While I suppose we could find some normal form (such as the difference of two sheaves), I cannot see how one can reduce to the case of a single sheaf.

I couldn't find any source filling those gaps (e.g., this document p.86 begins a sentence to adress the issue, but never ends it). My question is: did I miss something, or is it known that Hartshorne's hint is insufficient ?
I have been told that there are other ways to prove this result, namely using Chow groups ; I would rather like to focus my question on techniques reasonably available at this point of Hartshorne's book.

See here for what is in my opinion a pretty solid proof that's written with the technology available at that point in the book. It also shows that you have to do a fair bit of work before you can apply the hint.

@KReiser Thank you so much ! No wonder I couldn't get my strategy to work !
